# Add a backarrow with navigation drawer flutter app

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I'm creating Flutter app and I'm quite new to this tech.

I've made some android app in the past, but I guess this is quite different.

I want to have a navigation drawer in my app.
To do this, I've used this tutorial : https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-setting-up-a-navigation-drawer-with-multiple-fragments-widgets-1914fda3c8a8

Which is working perfectly.

But the drawer icon is always the same, and I want to have the back arrow instead of the drawer icon.

What changes do I need to make ? I've seen I should is a **Navigation** instead of a **drawer**, but I need the drawer too...

EDIT : 
Forgot to mention, I need the drawer icon on the homepage, and the back arrow on child fragment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change in AppBar, please see below code.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Change Icon Example"),
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.person),
      onPressed: () {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
      },
    ),
  ),
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      children: _listViewData
          .map((data) => ListTile(
                title: Text(data),
              ))
          .toList(),
    ),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Text('Main Body'),
  ),
);}
```

Thanks, please let me know if any problem.

Comment: Can you please give some explanations ? Have you seen the provided link ? Can't find what I need to change...

Comment: Yes, I have seen the link. Where 'appbar' is defined, there you can change icon, like I mentioned in my code. After you can call drawer code.

Comment: I don't need to change the default icon, I need to change the icon if the called fragment isn't my home page

Comment: I got your point. Please follow this URL of medium [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-vi-navigation-drawer-flutter-1-0-3a05e09b0db9) , easy steps please follow.

Answer (score 0):

> **You do like this:**

```
appBar: AppBar(
  leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {


              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.icon_name,

              ),
            ),

)
```